# How to write a TComponent descendant using WriteComponent method?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a basic class with list of properties. Then create the child class and add another properties. I need to store the component into file. But instead of storing child component, the parent is written.

Below is an exaple demonstrating the issue.

```
  MyComp1 = class(TComponent)
  strict private
    FS: string;
    FI: Integer;
  published
    property S: string read FS write FS;
    property I: Integer read FI write FI;
  end;

  MyComp2 = class(MyComp1)
  strict private
    FS2: string;
  published
    property S2: string read FS2 write FS2;
  end;

procedure SaveIt;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  C1: MyComp1;
  C2: MyComp2;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    C1 := MyComp1.Create(nil);
    C1.S := 'Hallo, World!';
    C1.I := 100500;
    C2 := MyComp2(C1);
    C2.S2 := 'Second string';
    MS.WriteComponent(C2);
    MS.Position := 0;
    MS.SaveToFile('C:\test.dat');
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Details:

I have functionality which is being expanded with time. So I created base class of TComponent (let's call it MyComp1) and variable of this type (MyComp: MyComp1). Once I expand functionality I create the descendent class from previous version (MyComp2 = class(MyComp1)) add new needed properties and assign its values like this

```
MyComp2(MyComp).S2 := 'Second string';
```

Then I need to save MyComp component into file but with child properties. 
I do create it like this

```
MyComp := MyComp2.Create(nil)
```

but saving it into file has only properties of MyComp1

Comment: Your code potentially corrupts heap and in any case is wrong. What is your real question?

Comment: the question is how to save descendant component having it declared as parent.

Comment: Are you aware that typecasting `C2 := MyComp2(C1)` is just an error? What are you trying to do should not work and potentially raises Access Violation.

Comment: You cannot typecast ancestor to descendant, like `C2 := MyComp2(C1)`; you can only typecast descendant to ancestor.

Comment: And I do this to read and write properties of descendant, but saving does not include descendant properties.

Comment: @Serg: you can typecast an ancestor pointer to a descendant pointer if the object is actually an instance of the descendant type (otherwise you could not typecast the `Sender` parameter of all VCL events, for instance). That is not the case in this stuation, though, which is why it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are instantiating an object of `MyComp1` but then typecasting it to `MyComp2`.  It is not an actual `MyComp2` object in memory, so writing values to `MyComp2` properties on a `MyComp1` object is an invalid operation that accesses memory that does not belong to the MyComp1 object, so it will crash at best and corrupt memory at worse.

The correct way to handle this situation is to create just an object instance of `MyComp2` by itself, not `MyComp1` at all.  `MyComp2` inherits members from `MyComp1`, so you can access `MyComp1` properties on a `MyComp2` object, eg:

```
procedure SaveIt;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  Comp: MyComp2;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Comp := MyComp2.Create(nil);
    try
      Comp.S := 'Hallo, World!';
      Comp.I := 100500;
      Comp.S2 := 'Second string';
      MS.WriteComponent(Comp);
    finally
      Comp.Free;
    end;
    MS.Position := 0;
    MS.SaveToFile('C:\test.dat');
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I agree with this code but this not what I need to do. I have variable of base class declared in version 1 with code to set its properties. In version 2 I create decendant class MyComp2 and create its instance assining to variable of parent (MyComp := MyComp2.Create(nil)). I do not want to rewrite setting of parent propertities in each descendant class and each new version since it's done using inheritance logic. I just want to set properties of decendant class. I thought typecasting is correct since I create an instance of MyComp2.

Comment: @Yuriy: then you are not showing us your actual code. You do show a couple of statements in your question where you create an instance of MyComp2, but it uses different variables from the code doing the WriteComponent. It's pretty hard, not to say impossible, to help you if you are not showing the actual code.